# bash output command not found

Tags: bash, echo

Im facing following problem I have created mentioned condition, but when I choose y for yes everything is ok, but when I choose n for not I get annoying error output:
output :
Do you agree yes (y) or not (n)
n
./myscript: [n: command not found

myscript is the name of my script
Code here:

```
echo  "Do you agree yes (y) or not (n)"
read  answer
if ( [ "$answer" =  'y' ]  ||  ["$answer" = 'Y' ]);
then

echo  -e  “  output for y”
done
else
echo -e "  output for n "
exit 1;
```

Any idea how can I get rid of the output and fix the problem ? 
thanks

Comment: it's not necessary to use the parentheses to group your test commands in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not bash.  "done" does not terminate an "if" condition in bash.  You should remove "done" and add "fi" at the end of the else body.

Also, the semicolon after "exit 1" is not needed.

Answer (score 7):

You missed the space in:

```
["$answer" = 'Y' ]
```

Change to:

```
[ "$answer" = 'Y' ]
```

There are also other mistakes in the script. Here you have working code:

```
echo  "Do you agree yes (y) or not (n)"
read  answer
if ( [[ "$answer" =  'y' ]] || [[ "$answer" = 'Y' ]]);
then
 echo -e "  output for y"
else
 echo -e "  output for n"
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: The x is in the test condition to work around bugs in ancient bourne and C shells. Use `[[`.

Comment: You're right, I just checked if lack of x wasn't the issue with the code, and forgot to remove it.

Comment: This is great!!

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a space after the `[` in your second condition.  `[` is actually a command and since it's together it tries to literally run `[n`. You don't see the output with `y` because the evaluation is short circuited (i.e. the first condition is true so there's no need to evaluate the second).

Answer (score 0):

done should be after the else clause, i.e., before exit. and it is "fi" not "done".